# Default value for default generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, inheritance, abstract-class, default

Consider a generic class:

```
abstract class Base<T={}> {
    public getSmth(): T {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want `getSmth` method to return `{}` if `T={}` and be abstract (require to be overriden in derived classes) for all other `T`. Cow can I do that?

I've tried following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Base%3CT%3D%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getSmth()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20need%20to%20override%20%60getSmth%60%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getSmth()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Need%20to%20override%20as%20generic%20differes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bx%3A%208%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20override%20for%20a%20generic%20parameter%20should%20be%20a%20error!%0D%0A%7D), but the problem is that there's no error for class `C`:

```
abstract class Base<T={}> {
    public getSmth(): T {
        return {} as T;
    }
}

class A extends Base<{}> {
    // No need to override `getSmth`
}

class B extends Base<{ x: number }> {
    public getSmth() { // Need to override as generic differes
        return {x: 8};
    }
}

class C extends Base<{ x: number }> {
    // No override for a generic parameter should be a error!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the method abstract for some values of `T` and not abstract for other values of `T` (even if the value is a default value for `T`). A better solution would be to make the method abstract and have a default implementation for `{}` if this a common case. This also avoid type assertions in the method.

```
abstract class Base<T> {
    public abstract getSmth(): T;
}
abstract class EmptyBase extends Base<{}> { // Implementation for {}
    public getSmth(): {} {
        return {}
    }
}

class A extends EmptyBase {
    // No need to override `getSmth` 
}

class B extends Base<{ x: number }> {
    public getSmth() { // Need to override as generic differes
        return {x: 8};
    }
}

class C extends Base<{ x: number;}> { // Must override error if you don't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use an additional interface, but in that case you'll need to specify it explicitely for every child class: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IBase%3CT%3D%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getSmth()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Base%3CT%3D%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getSmth()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%7D%3E%20implements%20IBase%3C%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20need%20to%20override%20%60getSmth%60%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20implements%20IBase%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getSmth()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Need%20to%20override%20as%20generic%20differes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bx%3A%208%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20implements%20IBase%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20override%20for%20a%20generic%20parameter%20should%20be%20a%20error!%0D%0A%7D)

```
interface IBase<T={}> {
    getSmth(): T;
}

abstract class Base<T={}> {
    public getSmth() {
        return {};
    }
}

class A extends Base<{}> implements IBase<{}> {
    // No need to override `getSmth`
}

class B extends Base<{ x: number }> implements IBase<{ x: number }> {
    public getSmth() { // Need to override as generic differes
        return {x: 8};
    }
}

class C extends Base<{ x: number }> implements IBase<{ x: number }> {
    // No override for a generic parameter should be a error!
}
```

And there will be a error:

> ```
> Class 'C' incorrectly implements interface 'IBase<{ x: number; }>'.
>   Types of property 'getSmth' are incompatible.
>     Type '() => {}' is not assignable to type '() => { x: number; }'.
>       Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ x: number; }'.
>         Property 'x' is missing in type '{}'.
> ```